# Is there any way to make multiple targets as series of single make invocations?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following `Makefile`:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
    -include generated.mk
endif

FOO ?= foo

all: a.txt

a.txt:
    echo $(GEN_FOO) > $@

generated.mk: Makefile
    echo GEN_FOO = $(FOO) > $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) a.txt
    $(RM) generated.mk
```

It works OK when building single targets:

```
$ make clean 
rm -f a.txt
rm -f generated.mk

$ make all
echo GEN_FOO = foo > generated.mk
echo foo > a.txt
```

However when I try to build multiple targets at once things go not so smooth:

```
$ make clean all
rm -f a.txt
rm -f generated.mk
echo foo > a.txt

$ make all
echo GEN_FOO = foo > generated.mk
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

It gets even worse if variables were provided:

```
$ make clean
rm -f a.txt
rm -f generated.mk

$ make FOO=bar clean all
echo GEN_FOO = bar > generated.mk
rm -f a.txt
rm -f generated.mk
echo bar > a.txt

$ make all
echo GEN_FOO = foo > generated.mk
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

$ make FOO=bar clean all
rm -f a.txt
rm -f generated.mk
echo foo > a.txt
```

Are there any ways to fix such incorrect behavior?

Comment: By "incorrect" do you mean "different from what you expected" or is there a standard that specifies a different beahvior?

Comment: Please always consider parallel _make_ in your thoughts. Does it make sense to do a `clean` and to build `all` at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make is doing exactly what you told it to do, and you haven't told *us* what you want it to do that's different than what you told it to do (saying *fix such incorrect behavior* doesn't really help us when you don't define what's incorrect about the behavior), so we can't help you very much.

You are probably getting confused about the interaction between included makefiles and comparing `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`.  Please note:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
```

this will not match unless you specify exactly one target: `clean`.  In situations where you specify multiple targets, one of which is clean, that will match because `clean all` is not equal to `clean`.  So, when you run `make clean all` make *will* include the generated makefile, and will generate it if it doesn't exist.

Because generated include files are only rebuilt once, when the makefile is first parsed, it's not possible to say something like: "first run rule X (e.g., `clean`) then rebuild the included makefiles, then reinvoke make".

However, it's pretty much always a bad idea to invoke make with `clean all`.  This is because if you were to ever try to add `-j` for parallelism, the clean and the build would be running in parallel and corrupt everything.

One semi-common option is to provide a different rule that will do both, something like this:

```
rebuild:
        $(MAKE) clean
        $(MAKE) all
```

then run `make rebuild` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, describing best practices and even providing a possible workaround, Paul! I definitely need to improve my question by describing the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly force the behavior with the help of the shell. For instance, in `bash` you could use

```
for target in "clean" "all";
do
   make $target;
done
```

and if you were going to re-do the procedure a lot you could either make it an executable script or wrap it in a shell function.